# How do I extract data from thousands of large NetCDF files in a performant way in Python?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a grid of approximately 500x1000 points with weather data. Each NetCDF file contains data for one day and I have data for several years. What I am trying to extract is all weather data for all times per point. So essentially I would like to split the data into 500000 files with data for one point in each.

What approach would be the best with respect to performance?

I tried to join all NetCDF files to one giant NetCDF file (appoximately 400 GB large). Then read it in with xarray and tried to split into one file per point. It took approximatelly 30 minutes per point, so I am looking for a faster solution.

```py
    import xarray as xr
    dataset = xr.open_dataset(big_nc_path)
    selected_data = dataset.isel(x=12, y=17)
    dataframe = selected_data.to_dataframe()
    dataframe.to_csv(file_path)
```

**Update 1:**

I have reduced the file to one year now to make it easier to test.
It seems like it was to large extent an IO issue since I had the large file on an external hard drive. Now I have moved it to my SSD and it is considerably faster.

Time to extract one x,y-combination when yearly file is on external hard drive: 10minutes and 40 seconds.

Time to extract one x,y-combination when yearly file is on SSD: 20 seconds.

Still interested in improvements though :)
I posted the output of nc_dump -hs here:
https://gist.github.com/robban/fd8f1b0e3228c0b80e93772976dc638a

Comment: "It took approximatelly 30 minutes per point". Is that possible? Surely, all you need to do is loop through the x's and y's? I cannot see how the final 3 lines takes 30 minutes to run. Have you profiled it?

Comment: How many times do you have? Can you execute a `ncdump -hs` for different netCDF files you have? The "big" one and the one sample for the "original" ones? share the output (i.e CDL) 

The chunking and unlimited dimensions are the key.

Comment: One possible approach is to decide how much memory you have available (the more the better), and loop through in batches of as many days as will fit in your memory cache, reading in the data for those days and then appending this part of the timeseries to all your output files (initialising the output files if it is the first batch). Make sure to define the time axis as the unlimited dimension in your output files, to allow you to extend the timeseries in this way.